# Linguistic studies of singing: prosody, structure, etc

Tags: prosody, descriptive-linguistics

What are some well known techniques in which singing, especially that from less-known languages, has been studied?

I'm particularly interested in prosodic analysis of singing and e.g. song-structure (refrain, chorus, etc).

Comment: Just one interesting thing about prosody and singing: in Chinese, Japanese, and in the neighbouring tonal languages, modern songs on TV are always shown with the subtitles, because the speakers of those languages cannot otherwise understand the lyrics, the melody of the song makes it impossible to hear the tonal patterns in the individual words.

Comment: I'm working on songs in a tonal amazonian language and think it'd make a cool paper, but looking for some literature and journals where I could find some inspiration on how such a paper is organized. Any tips?

Comment: Sorry, but tonal languages aren't what I like, I don't have a good ear, so I cannot help you with any references.

Comment: Related: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3309/how-do-tones-work-in-music-sung-in-tonal-languages-such-as-cantonese-or-mandari and http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/170/can-native-chinese-speakers-distinguish-tones-in-songs